# Jasper Report Duplex to identity card

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a jasper report duplex, that after print 4 records in a detail, print a back that refers to the 4 record in that detail(like a back). This is for identity card of my state(liek a card club). Can someone help me?

I have already tried create a second detail, but always when print a detail, print the second detail. It is not what I want, I want finish print 4 records of one detail and after print the another detail in the back of the page.

Answer (score 0):

add 2 detail bands into the report first one for front side and other for back side. then desired identity card's height set to detail band's height. please refer below example.

desired identity card's height = 125 px

```
<detail>
    <band height="125">
        <!-- other components -->
    </band>
    <band height="125">
        <!-- other components -->
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: I resolved cloning the list foreach 4 registers, because the page is filled with 4 registers. But thankyou, I will try your solution.